# FFmpeg os.system commands not working but work in Terminal

Tags: python, ffmpeg, terminal, operating-system

I've downloaded ffmpeg through the website and ran some commands through the terminal to confirm its install.

when running the command 'ffmpeg' in the Terminal it returns

```
 ffmpeg version 4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg 
 developers
 built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
```

if i type into Python

```
import os
os.system ('ffmpeg')
```

it returns

```
 os.system ('ffmpeg')
 sh: ffmpeg: command not found
 Out[25]: 32512
```

any ideas?

Solution:

```
 ffmpeg = '/bin/ffmpeg' #path to the binary file

 os.system(ffmpeg)
```

Output:

```
os.system (ffmpeg)
ffmpeg version 4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
```

Comment: PATH is different when you are using `os.system`. It won't solve your problem, but generally you should use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) instead.

Comment: Try giving it the full path to ffmpeg (i.e. 'my/path/ffmpeg.exe')

Comment: Working now! I have to have the binary file location within python in order for it to work

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
ffmpeg = '/bin/ffmpeg' #path to the binary file

os.system(ffmpeg)
Output:

os.system (ffmpeg)
ffmpeg version 4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the 
FFmpeg developers
built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
```